# Centering image inside SVG

Tags: html, css, image, svg, center

Is there some easy solution to center image on X and Y inside SVG? I have to keep svg element with percentage.

```css
svg {
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Izolovaný_režim" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 294.7 320.3" xml:space="preserve">

  <pattern id="img" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="100%" height="100%">
      <image xlink:href="https://cdn-mf0.heartyhosting.com/sites/mensfitness.com/files/styles/wide_videos/public/1280-fit-man-work-desk.jpg?itok=xpQGNXMI" x />
   </pattern>
             
        <g>
            <polygon points="147.4,320.3 294.7,235.2 294.7,85.1 147.4,0 0,85.1 0,235.2  " fill="url(#img)"/>
          
        </g>
 </svg>
```

Thank you. ;)

Comment: That is unclear. Please describe the desired relative positions and sizes of the image, the pattern, the polygon and the svg.

Answer (score -1):

To center you image pattern in the polygon you can use the `x` and `y` attributes of the `pattern` to set the origin of the image.

So in your case you could set it to `x="50%" y="50%"`

```css
svg {
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Izolovaný_režim" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 294.7 320.3" xml:space="preserve">

  <pattern id="img" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="100%" height="100%" x="50%" y="50%">
      <image xlink:href="https://cdn-mf0.heartyhosting.com/sites/mensfitness.com/files/styles/wide_videos/public/1280-fit-man-work-desk.jpg?itok=xpQGNXMI" x />
   </pattern>
             
        <g>
            <polygon points="147.4,320.3 294.7,235.2 294.7,85.1 147.4,0 0,85.1 0,235.2  " fill="url(#img)"/>
          
        </g>
 </svg>
```

Comment: Thanks but I think this didn´t solve my problem. I need to see the area which is here outlined: https://imgur.com/a/kVtA7